# Fourier transform of a Gaussian function in Python

Tags: python, fft, continuous-fourier

I want to calculate the Fourier transform of some Gaussian function. Consider the simple Gaussian g(t) = e^{-t^2}. The Fourier transform of g(t) has a [simple analytical expression](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html) , such that the 0th frequency is simply root pi.

If I try to do the same thing in Python:

```
N = 1000
t = np.linspace(-1,1,N)
g = np.exp(-t**2)

h = np.fft.fft(g) #This is the Fourier transform of expression g
```

Simple enough. Now [as per the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#background-information) `h[0]` should contain the zero frequency term, which we know from the analytical expression is root pi. But instead it gives `746.444`?!

Why the discrepancy between the analytical solution and the computational one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why do you think you should get analytical expression. DFFT in NUmPy is clearly asymmetrical, and if you look at formula for A<sub>k</sub> [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html), you could clearly see that for A<sub>0</sub> you ought to get sum of input. Also, having gaussian from [-sigma...sigma] interval is not right.

Here is modified example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 4001
t = np.linspace(-4.0, 4.0, N)
print((t[0], t[2000], t[4000]))
g = np.exp(-t*t)
print(np.sum(g)) # sum of input

h = np.fft.fft(g, norm=None)
print(h[0]) # should be the same as sum of input
```

and it prints

```
(-4.0, 0.0, 4.0)
886.2269119018041
(886.226911901804+0j)
```

You could do inverse transform and plot it

```
q = np.fft.ifft(h, norm=None)

plt.plot(t, g, label = "Gauss")
plt.show()
plt.plot(t, np.abs(q), label = "dFFT Gauss")
plt.show()
f = np.fft.fftfreq(N)
plt.plot(f, np.angle(h), f, np.abs(h))
plt.show()
```

and get

[image]

Comment: Hmmm ok this is v.helpful - but I am still confused: the link effectively states that h(0) = root pi. I think you have explained it slightly re "DFFT in NUmPy is clearly asymmetrical", but it is still not fully clear to me why h(0) does not equal root pi

Comment: @user1887919 Well, this is convention used in NumPy. There are libraries which have multiple options for scaling forth and  back (like likefftw3 in C and mathdotnet in C#), but in NumPy as far as I can see there are only two options - nothing forward and 1/N inverse scaling (norm=None, which you and I used) or 1/sqrt(N) scaling for both forward and inverse transform ("ortho" option). Neither of those options will produce sqrt(pi). You could probably wrap NumPy FFT into your own routines which do proper scaling in and out.

Comment: @user1887919 You could take a look at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15770-scaling-the-fft-and-the-ifft, it is Matlab, but discussion about scaling is quite good