# Plotting Fourier Transform of Gaussian function with python, but the result was wrong

Tags: python, fft, gaussian

I have been thinking about it for a long time, but I don't find out what the problem is. Hope you can help me, Thank you.

```
F(s) Gaussian function
F(s)=1/(√2π s) e^(-(w-μ)^2/(2s^2 ))
```

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import pi
from scipy.fft import fft

def F_S(w, mu, sig):
    return (np.exp(-np.power(w-mu, 2)/(2 * np.power(sig, 2))))/(np.power(2*pi, 0.5)*sig)

w=np.linspace(-5,5,100)
plt.plot(w, np.real(np.fft.fft(F_S(w, 0, 1))))
plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: what do you expect it to be?

Comment: I want to get the curve after Fourier Transform of the Gaussian function

Comment: and how should that look compared to what you get as an answer?

Comment: Gaussian function should still be Gaussian after FT

Comment: If you want the plot to look like another Gaussian, you need to reorder coefficients, fix up the scalings, etc., according to whatever your DFT routine is doing.

Comment: You should not take the real component of the result, but its absolute value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Analytical Fourier transform vs FFT of functions in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317834/analytical-fourier-transform-vs-fft-of-functions-in-matlab)

Comment: The linked answer uses MATLAB, not Python, but the concepts are identical. It should explain exactly what the issue is with your code.

Comment: Thanks for everyone, the problem is solved,  I found a related question 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398304/fourier-transform-of-a-gaussian-is-not-a-gaussian-but-thats-wrong-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned before you want the absolute value, not the real part. 
A minimal example, showing the the re/im , abs/phase spectra.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline

n=1001                       # add 1 to keep the interval a round number when using linspace
t = np.linspace(-5, 5, n )   # presumed to be time
dt=t[1]-t[0]                 # time resolution
print(f'sampling every  {dt:.3f} sec , so at {1/dt:.1f} Sa/sec, max. freq will be {1/2/dt:.1f} Hz')


y = np.exp(-(t**2)/0.01)      # signal in time

fr= np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(n, dt))  # shift helps with sorting the frequencies for better plotting
ft=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y))           # fftshift only necessary for plotting in sequence

p.figure(figsize=(20,12))
p.subplot(231)
p.plot(t,y,'.-')
p.xlabel('time (secs)')
p.title('signal in time')

p.subplot(232)
p.plot(fr,np.abs(ft), '.-',lw=0.3)      
p.xlabel('freq (Hz)')
p.title('spectrum, abs');

p.subplot(233)
p.plot(fr,np.real(ft), '.-',lw=0.3)     
p.xlabel('freq (Hz)')
p.title('spectrum, real');

p.subplot(235)
p.plot(fr,np.angle(ft), '.-', lw=0.3)    
p.xlabel('freq (Hz)')
p.title('spectrum, phase');

p.subplot(236)
p.plot(fr,np.imag(ft), '.-',lw=0.3)      
p.xlabel('freq (Hz)')
p.title('spectrum, imag');
```

[image]

Comment: I truly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

you have to change from time scale to frequency scale

Comment: please look at these examples to see how to transform from time scale into frequency scale https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html

Answer (score 0):

When you make a FFT you will get the simetric tranformation, i.e, mirror of the positive to negative curve. Usually, you only will look at the positive side. 
Also, you should take care with sample rate, as FFT is designed to transform **time domain** input to **frequency domain**, the time, or sample rate, of input info matters.  So add timestep in `np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=timestep)` for your sample rate.

If you simple want to make a fft of  normal dist signal, here is another question with it and some good explanations on why are you geting this behavior:

[Fourier transform of a Gaussian is not a Gaussian, but thats wrong! - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398304/fourier-transform-of-a-gaussian-is-not-a-gaussian-but-thats-wrong-python)

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code:

- Don't take the real part, take the absoulte value when plotting.
- From the docs:

> If `A = fft(a, n)`, then `A[0]` contains the zero-frequency term (the mean
>   of the signal), which is always purely real for real inputs. Then
>   `A[1:n/2]` contains the positive-frequency terms, and `A[n/2+1:]` contains
>   the negative-frequency terms, in order of decreasingly negative
>   frequency.

You can rearrange the elements with [`np.fft.fftshift`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html).

The working code:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import pi
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftshift

def F_S(w, mu, sig):
    return (np.exp(-np.power(w-mu, 2)/(2 * np.power(sig, 2))))/(np.power(2*pi, 0.5)*sig)

w=np.linspace(-5,5,100)
plt.plot(w, fftshift(np.abs(np.fft.fft(F_S(w, 0, 1)))))
plt.show()
```

Also, you might want to consider scaling the x axis too.